# Reuse constructor parameters in child class

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to reuse base class `Person`  constructor in `Instructor` class but add additional parameter `degree`. Somehow it doesn't work. Please check further info:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name = 'Jane Doe', year = 2000):
        self.n = name
        self.y = year
        
class Instructor(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, year, degree=12):
         super().__init__(name, year) #call base class ctor
         self.degree = degree;
```

Neveretheless when i do this:

```
sammy = Instructor("John") # i want to set John as name
```

I am getting following error:

```
Exception has occured: TypeError __init__() missing 1 required positional arguments year
```

**Since year & degree having default values i do not understand the error.**

Comment: `year` does not have a default value in `Instructor` init method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment suggests, you have to set default value for `Instructor`'s `init`.
While you are creating an object of `Instructor` the `Instructor`'s constructor is called before the `Person`'s constructor. So it doesn't care about default values in the `Person`'s constructor.

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name = 'Jane Doe', year = 2000):
        self.n = name
        self.y = year
        
class Instructor(Person):
    def __init__(self, name = 'Jane Doe', year = 2000, degree=12):
         super().__init__(name, year) #call base class ctor
         self.degree = degree;
```

And then:

```py
sammy = Instructor("John")
```

runs without exception.

Comment: so by means to reuse constructore i do always need to have default values given? For instance in other languages like Microsoft's C# it's not required

Comment: @Arie As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The first `__init__` that runs is the `Instructor`'s init. That's why you get the error. Setting a default value for year will run without exception.